# Google Play Services need to update in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

Google Play Services need to update in `android studio` emulator. But if I press update nothing happens. I am using api 23.1.1. I need to use the op `play services` to use `Google Cloud Messaging`. how do you need to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue before by changing a line in my build.gradle file

from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
```

Comment: Yes I have tried tis as wel. But what is the real difference between these once

Comment: Sometimes, what is reflected on the gradle is not the actual version and by putting `+` the app will automatically use the latest version available.

Answer (score 1):

Run SDK Manager.exe you will get a pop up of Android SDK Manager. At the bottom u will find Select New or Updates. Then you can select the updated google play services and install the package.

Comment: Is it possible that I need to change my API level? but how do I do that?

Comment: I tried by changing it in the project structure and build.gradle but it gives my errors

Comment: Ya you can delete the current api and upgrade to latest api in sdk manager and in such case you need to rebuild ur project on the newly installed version. Also u can try changing the min api version and target api version in manifest file.

Comment: And to what do I need to change it?

Comment: If u upgrade api to new level, sometimes, new versions of api may not support ur project as they were built on lower version. In such cases u need to specify the mentioned changes in manifest file and rebuild the project to run in new api level.

Comment: Can't get it to work. And I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: When i run the same code with the same API level on my android device. I get an error "GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin."