# Error on gcmquickstart-asking for update google playstore

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'am trying to implement gcmquickstart but the emulator is showing update google play store,which i have already installed and updated.Following is my screen shots of error logs and image of emulator[image].Can somebody help me to solve??????????
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to use an emulator with play services. You can download from SDK Manager.

Comment: You may check the possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350947/googe-play-services-need-to-update-in-android-studio-emulator).

Comment: thanks a lot ...............friends